# String that contains a SELECT with several pairs of variables and values. Using EXEC gives me an undeclared variable error

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

The process is more complex than the previous one.
I have a stored procedure that retrieves the variable `@parameters_list NVARCHAR(2000)`.

This `@parameters_list` variable contains a series of parameters that I retrieve from a transactional website. Usually, it contains a series of parameters with their respective values. The parameters vary depending on the type of transaction being executed.

Here is a more complete description of the process:

Suppose, that `@parameters_list` comes with the following data from the website

```
@parameters_list    = 'id_client=1;id_dealer=1;id_country=1;id_region=5;id_city=2;sede=2;id_tower=8;main_code=CHI-01-01;id_location=2;city=Main City;data_name=Box 01;title=Major KPI;tittle2=Detecting relevant Data;detail=none'
```

Inside the stored procedure, I have in part the following declarations and creation of a temporary table:

```
DECLARE @id_client          INT,
        @id_dealer          INT,
        @id_country         INT,
        @id_region          INT,
        @id_city            INT,
        @id_tower           INT,
        @main_code          VARCHAR(120),
        @id_location        INT,
        @city               VARCHAR(50),
        @data_name          VARCHAR(100),
        @detail             VARCHAR(100),
        @title              VARCHAR(200),
        @title2             VARCHAR(300)

DECLARE @stringData         NVARCHAR(2000),
        @data_key           VARCHAR(30)

DECLARE @ident              INT

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TEMP_DATA](
    [ident] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data_key] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [data_value] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Later, I execute another stored procedure (`PANKI_UTILS..SP_KEY_VALUE_PARAMETER`) whose main task is to separate the variables with their respective values. Then, the result is stored in the temporary table `#TEMP_DATA`.

```
EXEC PANKI_UTILS..SP_KEY_VALUE_PARAMETER 
    @parameters_list,
    ';',
    '=',
    @ident output

    INSERT INTO 
    #TEMP_DATA
    SELECT 
    [key],
    value 
    FROM PANKI_UTILS..KEY_VALUE 
    WHERE ind = @ident
    ORDER BY [key]
```

The content of the #`TEMP_DATA` table is as follows:

[image: temporary table with data_key and data_value fields]

What the image shows is a table where the column `data_key` is the name of the variable and "data value" the value of that variable.

Finally, I store all the content of the table in a `@stringData` variable

```
SET @stringData = (SELECT string_agg('@'+CAST(data_key AS VARCHAR(30)) +'='+ CAST(data_value AS VARCHAR(500)), ',') FROM #TEMP_DATA)

SELECT  @stringData

@city=Main City,@data_name=Box 01,@detail=none,@id_city=2,@id_client=1,@id_country=1,@id_dealer=1,@id_location=2,@id_region=5,@id_sede=2,@id_tower=8,@main_code=CHI-01-01,@title=Major KPI,@tittle2=Detecting relevant Data
```

That's why I'm looking for a way to retrieve the variables in the form of; `@city`, `@data_name` and etc.

An alternative was to use the `sp_executesql` command, but I don't really know how to use it to retrieve those variables.
If you can help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I don't see any declare statements. Though agreed with the above, what is the ultimate goal, i.e. Why do you believe you need EXEC?

Comment: If you really need dynamic SQL, and you wish to pass parameters, use `sp_executesql`. In fact use `sp_executesql` over `exec` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The TSQL you provide as a parameter to `execute` is run in a different scope than your parent script. It doesn't have access to local variables declared outside of it.

If you need to use `execute`, try something like this:

```sql
declare @string_data varchar(max);

SET @string_data = '

declare @City varchar(255), @Product varchar(255) , @Zip varchar(255);

SELECT @city=''Baltimore'', @product= ''car'', @zip=''630930'';

SELECT @city AS city, @product AS product, @zip AS zip;
';

EXEC(@string_data);
```

But you might be able to get away without using it:

```sql
declare @City varchar(255), @Product varchar(255) , @Zip varchar(255);

SELECT @city='Baltimore', @product= 'car', @zip='630930';

SELECT @city AS city, @product AS product, @zip AS zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `EXEC(@String)`, you're opening a new session and starting a new transaction. That new session that is opened is not aware of any variable from the calling session that executed the EXEC command.

Further, it doesn't really look like you need to use dynamic SQL and execute right here.

Without know what the rest of your query looks like, try this.

```
SELECT @city=Baltimore, @product= car, @zip=630930

SELECT @city AS city, @product AS product, @zip AS zip
```